# python: syntactic sugar - is it official? where is it described in documentation?

Tags: python, syntactic-sugar

I often see notes that e.g. `[]`is syntactic sugar for `_getitem_` ([Why/How does Pandas use square brackets with .loc and .iloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176656/why-how-does-pandas-use-square-brackets-with-loc-and-iloc)), but neither by web search, not here on SO, not in glossary in [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) I could find list of all sugars for Python. Are sugars official or left to each implementation specifics?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's documented in the [Python data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types).
It's not exactly synthetic sugar, and more of an implementation detail of how container types work. Python has lots of these so-called "magic methods"

Comment: thank you! I've found _getitem_ in pandas source https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py and now understand who it is working.