# Is loc[ ] a function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Normal syntax for calling a function is func() but I have noticed that loc[] in pandas is without parentheses and still treated as a function. Is loc [] really a function in pandas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why/How does Pandas use square brackets with .loc and .iloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176656/why-how-does-pandas-use-square-brackets-with-loc-and-iloc)

Comment: The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176656/why-how-does-pandas-use-square-brackets-with-loc-and-iloc) linked by @user202729 (that was closed and not answered) wasn't a duplicate. Now that it was reopened, however, I added an answer there that includes my answer here and goes more into depth on the "why" this syntax is used. @ OP would you consider taking a look at the *other* question and see if this might be considered a duplicate now?

Answer (score 4):

> Is loc[ ] a function in Pandas?

No. The simplest way to check is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
print(df.loc.__class__)
```

which prints

```
<class 'pandas.core.indexing._LocIndexer'>
```

this tells us that `df.loc` is an instance of a `_LocIndexer` class. The syntax `loc[]` derives from the fact that [`_LocIndexer` defines `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`<sup>*</sup>](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f79468b8642be1ebc24b806117505a6fa7bf50b7/pandas/core/indexing.py#L930), which are the methods python calls whenever you use the square brackets syntax.

---

<sup>*Technically, it's its base class `_LocationIndexer` that defines those methods, I'm simplifying a bit here</sup>

Answer (score 0):

LOC[] is a **property** that allows Pandas to query data within a dataframe in a standard format. Basically you're providing the index of the data you want.

Comment: *"Basically you're providing the address of the data you want."*.. no, you're not providing any address. At best, you're providing the *index* of the data you want, but that's also not answering the question of "how does this work"

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple DataFrame `df` and look at the type of df.loc:

```
>>> type(df.loc)
pandas.core.indexing._LocIndexer
```

This means calling `loc` on a DataFrame returns an object of the type `_LocIndexer`, so `.loc` is not a function or method.

Look at what happens when we inspect the type of an actual function / method of a DataFrame:

```
>>> type(df.rename)
method
```

So what really happens here, is that you are accessing an attribute of your DataFrame called `loc`, which contains an object of type `_LocIndexer`, which itself implements the dunder methods `__getitem__`. This is a magic method that can be implemented by an object in order to define what happens when the object is indexed with the square bracket notation, just like a list or a dictionary.